# Losing superscript tag when converting HTML to DOCX using libreoffice

Tags: html, converters, docx, libreoffice

I have the following HTML:

`<html><body><p>n<sup>th</sup></p></body></html>`

I am using the command:

> $ libreoffice --convert-to docx:"MS Word 2007 XML" test.html

To convert that HTML into a DOCX file. However I notice that the resulting DOCX file does not actually contain the `<sup>` tag. It looks like it is using position and size to replicate the `<w:vertAlign>` tag:

`<w:position w:val="8"/><w:sz w:val="19"/>`

What I would need to know is how to make libreoffice put in the `<w:vertAlign>` tag instead of using position and size.

Additonal Info:

I had a similar problem with bold and italics (`<strong><em>`) but was able to get the conversion to work correctly if I converted the `strong` and `em` tags to `b` and `i` tags respectively.

Comment: I've had similar issues with the libreoffice convert-to docx and spent too much time trying to figure out which tags converted correctly and did not. I've had more consistent success using: https://cloudconvert.org/html-to-docx     If you are in a crunch for time I would suggest trying this alternative. Specifically I know that it handles the <sup> tag properly.

Comment: @BrianGilreath I tried the tool you mentioned with the exact HTML that was posted with my question. The `sup` was still converted to position and size instead of `vertAlign`

Comment: could this be a doctype issue? if you declare html5 doctype before the opening html element, will you get a different result?

Comment: Do you need to convert it via libreoffice ?

Comment: @albert I have tried different doctypes, none of them seem to help here. @ user3241019 I don't need to convert using libreoffice, however that is the best tool I have found in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to edit the HTML, it would be much better to use a tool that is suited for editing HTML, such as Notepad++ or Sublime (as examples).

If you need to have the HTML as a LibreOffice document for a specific reason, you could open the HTML file in Notepad and save as a text file with .txt as the extension. That should allow you to open the document in LibreOffice.

Comment: I am looking to give our users the ability to edit HTML, even though most of our users are not familiar with HTML. Most of our users are quite proficient with Microsoft Word, so it makes sense to convert the HTML to DOCX for editing in word. I already have a tool to convert the DOCX file back to HTML.

Comment: It's been a while since I've been new to HTML, so just asking...Notepad is too much to ask them to learn? It's not meant to be a derogatory question, merely curious. Learning the right tools is really the beginning to learn to program. There's also online tools that allow you to code completely within the browser, like: http://scratchpad.io/

Comment: Our users have zero technical background. In order for them to use Notepad they would first need to learn how to structure HTML. Our tool gives them a way to edit their documents with a tool they are familiar with (Microsoft Word). We currently have a "What You Mean Editor" that is a JS tool to edit HTML in a word like fashion. However it's clunky and a bit buggy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using a WYSIWYG(What You See Is What You Get) editor like TinyMCE(http://www.tinymce.com/). There are lots of them online and you can also find some desktop applications for that. but if you want to convert it in docx you can try this http://htmltodocx.codeplex.com/ it is written in php and uses PHPWord and is quite efficient.

Comment: We already use a WYSIWYG editor (https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor)[wymeditor]. We are specifically trying to get around using it since our customers are not as comfortable using the WYSIWYG editor compared to Microsoft Word. I looked into `htmltodocx` briefly, however we don't use PHP nor is that something we want to use. What I want to do is find a way to tell libreoffice what these tags are supposed to be and the conversion work with libreoffice, like my question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Just create a Python script that replaces your unwanted tags with the `<w:vertAlign>` tag where ever needed.

Comment: And how do you propose that I find the tags that are messed up and replace them with the `<w:vertAlign>` tag? Considering that they will almost certainly look different depending on fonts, margins, etc.

Answer (score 1):

The command works fine if you replace 'docx' with 'xml', like this:

```
libreoffice --convert-to xml:"MS Word 2003 XML" test.html
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I need the resulting document to be a docx file as I am using PyDocx to convert the file back to HTML when the user is done editing the document.

Comment: I believe MS Word can edit HTML docs directly (correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: Not very well. We do a lot of post processing on the resulting HTML. Regardless. If I was not clear in the question that I wanted a DOCX file then please let me know so I can clear that up.